# Change Date Format In Lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

From lightning component, when I select the startdate and end date, I should able to select in `MM-DD-YYY`. But from backend Apex, it is coming as `YYY-MM-DD 00:00:00`. I want to convert this into that format. How can I do it?

Below is my code markup:

```
<ui:inputDate aura:id="startDate" required="true"   class="field"  displayDatePicker="true"   value="{!v.StartDate}" format="MM-DD-YYYY" blur="{!c.changeDateFormat}"/>

<ui:inputDate aura:id="endDate" required="true"   class="field"  displayDatePicker="true"   value="{!v.EndDate}" format="MM-DD-YYYY" blur="{!c.changeDateFormat}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the link below and compare the 2 input-types: Date (entering a date) and Datetime-local (entering a date and time).
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_input.htm

Answer (score -1):

The controller (js) is receiving the value correctly, right? (MM-DD-YYYY)

That's a string, so your apex code needs to receive a String too, for exemple :

Component:

```
<ui:inputDate aura:id="date-id" value="{!date}" displayDatePicker="true" blur="{!c.fldChanged}"/>
```

Controller :

```
fldChanged : function(component, event, helper) {
        var dateComponent = event.getSource();
        var newDateJs = dateComponent.get("v.value");
        var action = component.get("c.updateVisitDate");
            action.setParams({newDate: newDateJs });
            action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
                var state = response.getState();
            if (state === 'SUCCESS'){                  
                $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
```

Apex:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void updateVisitDate(String newDate){
     // do your stuff   
}
```

Comment: `Date` type will work here, no need to pass as `String` and then convert to `Date`.